# Insert pdf as a package from VBA, to avoid application associations

Tags: vba, ms-word, createoleobject

I am attempting to speed up insertion of pdf's as embedded files into a Word document.

In MS Word, from the insert object dialog, it is possible to select 'package' as an option.  Doing this avoids the automatic association of the inserted file with a particular application, which is required, as not all users of this document have the same PDF reader installed.

After manually inserting a file that does not have associations, I have switched to field codes to view the class type of the inserted package, the field code reads: { EMBED Package }

So I have tried the following:

```
Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        ClassType:="Package", _
        FileName:=FiletoInsert, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        Range:=Application.Selection.Range.Next(Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1)
```

But the embedded file resulting from this is still associated with Foxit or Adobe applications.

On comment suggestion, I've tried the macro recorder to check the parameters input by the application when using that approach, output in Macro:

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Package", FileName:="", _
      LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
      "C:\WINDOWS\system32\packager.dll", IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="Package"
```

I have tried changes based on this, but still including the FileName of the file to be inserted, but the application association remains.

How do I go about embedding these files without the association with an application, so that any user can open the pdf?

Comment: Have you tried using a macro recorder available in Word to find properties and methods required to get the job done?

Comment: What Word version do you use?

Comment: @KJ, I tried setting the default for PDFs in Windows to Edge and trying the insertion again, even restarting the system, but it still created the association with Foxit, which was the preceding default.

Comment: @FaneDuru, we're using 365 for enterprise.